# spring nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

i tried hard to get rid of this error, but it doesnt want to leave me.

here is the config xml

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

when i am trying to run the project i am getting this error

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring
>   threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before
>   instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice**
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:457)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:786)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.isInfrastructureClass(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:384)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:894)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:866)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:451)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:786)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

my messages properties file is in resources package in classpath. Someone please tell me what i am missing i added **aopalliance-alpha1.jar** also

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to addition of wrong JAR.

Expected JAR:- aopalliance.jar
Actual Jar :- aopalliance-alpha1.jar

Downlaod link:- http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/files/aopalliance/1.0/

Comment: I have this dependece in maven and it doesn't work: `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 8):

the problem was aopalliance-alpha1.jar, add aopalliance.jar instead, i found tht the error is caused by missing class in aopalliance-alpha1.jar, which is present in aopalliance.jar
:)

Comment: I have this dependece in maven and it doesn't work: `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency should works, another null error may occures, you need add default constructor to target class.

`<dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.11</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

I just add 
`<dependency>`
    `<groupId>aspectj</groupId>`
    `<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>`
    `<version>1.5.4</version>`


aopalliance
aopalliance
1.0
`
and it is working.