# Spring: nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

Tags: java, spring

**Stack trace:**

```
Oct 24, 2014 8:12:04 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@50df2e: startup date [Fri Oct 24 08:12:04 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 24, 2014 8:12:05 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [knights-aop.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [knights-aop.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.java.spring.SpringDemo.main(SpringDemo.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.getAdviceClass(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:410)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.createAdviceDefinition(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:366)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parseAdvice(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:332)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parseAspect(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:227)
    at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
```

config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="knight" class="com.java.spring.BraveKnight">
    <constructor-arg ref="quest" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="quest" class="com.java.spring.ResqueDamselQuest" />

  <bean id="minstrel" 
     class="com.java.spring.Minstrel" /> <!--<co id="co_minstrel_bean"/>-->

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">

      <aop:pointcut id="embark" 
          expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" /> <!--<co id="co_define_pointcut"/>-->

      <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark"
                  method="singBeforeQuest"/>    <!--<co id="co_minstrel_before_advice"/>-->

      <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark"
                 method="singAfterQuest"/>     <!--<co id="co_minstrel_after_advice"/>-->

    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>
</beans>
```

My main class:

```
public class SpringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("knights-aop.xml");
        final Knight braveKnight = (Knight) applicationContext.getBean("knight");
        braveKnight.embarkOnQuest();
    }
}
```

I also tried adding: aopalliance.jar & aopalliance-alpha1.jar individually and together but the error won't go away.

There are similar questions here on SO: [spring nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16458816/768894)

**###########EDIT###########Update: Other classes in the project##**
Minstrel.java

```
package com.java.spring;

    public class Minstrel {
        public void singBeforeQuest(){
            System.out.println("Fa la la Theknight is so brave!");
        }
        public void singAfterQuest(){
            System.out.println(
                    "Tee hee he The brave knight did embark on a quest!");
        }
    }
```

BraveKnight.java

```
package com.java.spring;

public class BraveKnight implements Knight {
    private Quest quest;

    BraveKnight(Quest quest) {
        this.quest = quest;
    }

    @Override
    public void embarkOnQuest() {
        quest.embark();
    }
}
```

RescueDamselQuest.java

```
package com.java.spring;

    public class RescueDamselQuest implements Quest {

        @Override
        public void embark() {
            System.out.println("Damsel rescue quest is on.");
        }
    }
```

I am using Spring 3.2
**##################EDIT2##################**
I am not using Maven. Please don't provide Maven related solution unless Spring AOP is impossible without it.

**Project Snap:**
[image]

Inside SPRING LIBRARY I have all the jar that got downloaded with Spring. Is it possible that some spring specific jar conflicting with aopalliance jar?

**If anyone has some similar & simple working example without Maven, please provide it.**
Thanks
~Mohit

Comment: Add `aopalliance.jar` if you state you have added it you added it wrong or are missing another class. I strongly suggest using something like maven to manage your dependencies instead of trying to figure them out for yourself.

Comment: It is a pretty basic dummy app. I think using Maven just yet might be a bit overkill, may be after the app grows.

Comment: Even with a basic app it pays off, saves you a lot of time searching for dependencies.

Comment: Also you might want to use a more recent spring version.

Comment: You are using mvn or some one like that? add the dependency, the problem is because you are using one module of maven that use another java projet, normally one implementation of some interface...

Comment: @nicearma I am not using maven.

Comment: @mohit so added to the IDE that you are using [path jar dependency] or use the manual way, i made one mistake about my comment "you are using one module of maven"->"you are using one module of SPRING that..."

Comment: @nicearma I am not understanding anything. I am using a simple example from the book "Spring In Action", I learned online that I need to add aopalliance.jar to my classpath along with other Spring dependencies but I am getting this error. Other programs related to dependency injection work perfectly. Only problem is with AOP.

Comment: I've just controlled it, the class `org.aopalliance.aop.Advice` is present in `aopalliance-1.0.jar`. Can you confirm that the file `knights-aop.xml` is what you showed under the name `config xml` ?

Comment: You say you *added it to classpath*. Can you confirm your application is standalone (not a web application), and if yes, how you added it to classpath ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Well, I tried with opalliance-1.0.jar too. Same error shows up. yes the actual file name is knights-aop.xml. The application is standalone and NOT a web app. To add the jar I did Right Click->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Libraries(tab)->Add External Jars..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed SPRING-LIBRARY completely and then added all the required jars one by one plus cglib-nodep-2.2.jar.
There was also a spelling mistake in my code `<bean id="quest" class="com.java.spring.ResqueDamselQuest" />`

```
public class RescueDamselQuest implements Quest {
```

Name of class.

But I am sure this spelling mistake was not the reason for the exception I was getting. After adding the jars from scratch I got this error that said the bean is not found as mentioned in the knights-aop.xml sth.. sth... which is when I figured that I have this typo.

This is how my jars are added now:

[image]

I hope someone might get help from this answer.

**###########EDIT###########**

asm-all & cglib-nodep are not required. Also, some jar from spring download was causing problems, as I tried adding all the jars I got in spring download and it started showing the old exception again. So it is better to add jar as and when required.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you only add the `aopalliance` jar to the *build classpath* of your IDE (Eclipse ?). That explains that the IDE shows no error and accepts to build the application. But in fact, you must also add it to the *run classpath*.

Depending on the IDE you use, another menu may allow to configure it. But if you want to run it outside the IDE, you must put the jar in your normal classpath, either by putting it along with other existing jars, or (would be better) by changing you user or system classpath to include the folder that contains the jar.

I could elaborate on that if you need and if I know your system ...

Comment: I am using Eclipse 4.4.0. I have no plans to run it outside IDE for now.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to configure run path for Eclipse, and currently have no access to an Eclipse IDE. You can try with `Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath` but I could not test. If it is not successful, it should work if you add the directory containing `aopalliance` jar to the environment variable `CLASSPATH`

Comment: It shows my added jar under classpath in Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath

Comment: 4 upvotes!!! Does it mean that this answer works for 4 different guys and not for the one who is desperately looking for the answer???

Answer (score 0):

cross check with com.springsource.org.aopalliance-X.X.X.jar

Comment: I am quite sure I have checked almost all the possible jars available online :(. If you have some similar & simple working example without Maven, please provide it. It would be great help.I am struggling with this for last 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the dependency. Not sure how you're handling dependencies, but just add the JAR in IVY or whatever you use.  You must be using something to add Spring 3.2.

Maven Central: [link](http://goo.gl/bs5sk6)

IVY Example: `<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aop" rev="3.2.11.RELEASE" />`
Maven has other dependency information available.

If this is a web app, make sure the JAR is in APPNAME/WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Be totally sure you have the following in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

According with your error stack trace.

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice`

The following is **mandatory**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course you must set or configure each version, for Spring and AOP.

I did realize later you are not working with Maven, even with that in [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) you are able to download the **jars** required according with my dependencies shared above

Answer (score 0):

Along with aopalliance jar have you added these jars into your build path??

aspectjrt 
springaop  
aspectjweaver

If not, you can try by adding these..
P.S: use the appropriate version of jars...

Comment: You didn't mention the appropriate versions of the jar or the way to figure out. I used spring-aop-3.2.10, aopalliance-1.0,aspectjrt-1.5.0, aspectjweaver-1.8.2. I am getting the same error.